# Access S3 from Amazon ML

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am evaluating Amazon ML and I am unable to use any S3 file. Even the sample "aml-sample-data/banking.csv" gives me the same error: *We are unable to read your S3 file. Make sure this is a CSV formatted file and UTF-8 encoded.*

Should I have any configuration to use the product? I thought the sample would be already configured.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the specific access level for Amazon ml to the specific S3 file. The security settings has to be matching at both end and can be easily done using ui.